# depth loop an array use block or something others

Tags: ios, iteration, block, traversal

I had an comments array, witch contains the comment message and the reply message and follow the reply message.want to show all the messages orderly, seems its An infinite loop.

My code is like below:

```
if (self.commentArray.count > 0) {
    //comments
    NSDictionary *message = [self.commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([FHWServiceManager isValidObject:[message objectForKey:@"UserIcon"]]) {
        [cell.photoImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[message objectForKey:@"UserIcon"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face_poor"]];
    }else {
        cell.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face_poor"];
    }

    cell.photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    cell.photoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.nameLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"Username"];
    cell.nameLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xbf6327);
    cell.contentLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"Comment"];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [DateUtil timePassedDescriptionFor:[DateUtil dateFromRFC3339DateString:[message objectForKey:@"CreateTime"]]];

    //follow comment
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PId == %d",[[message objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue]];
    NSArray *tempArray = [self.replyCommentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (tempArray.count > 0) {
        UIImageView *triangleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(67, 80, 10, 5)];
        triangleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment_reply_arrow_top"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:triangleImageView];

        UIView *followBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 85, 245, tempArray.count * 21 + 10)];
        followBackView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xf6f6f6);
        followBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

        float lastHeight = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.count; i ++) {
            NSDictionary *replyMessage = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString *replyStr;

            replyStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Comment"]];
            TTTAttributedLabel *followCommentLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, lastHeight + 5, followBackView.frame.size.width, 21)];
            //                        followCommentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            followCommentLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
            followCommentLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            followCommentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [followCommentLabel setText:replyStr afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
                NSRange redColorRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Username"]] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                // Core Text APIs use C functions without a direct bridge to UIFont. See Apple's "Core Text Programming Guide" to learn how to configure string attributes.
                NSDictionary *colorDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:UIColorFromRGB(0xbf6327),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttributes:colorDic range:redColorRange];

                return mutableAttributedString;
            }];
            [followBackView addSubview:followCommentLabel];

            UIButton *followButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            followButton.frame = followCommentLabel.frame;

            NSString *identify = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            [followButton setTitle:identify forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            followButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFollowComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            followButton.tag = indexPath.row + 10000;
            [followBackView addSubview:followButton];
            [followBackView bringSubviewToFront:followButton];
            //                            CGSize size = [followCommentLabel.text sizeWithFont:followCommentLabel.font
            //                                                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240, 800)
            //                                                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            //                            followCommentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 418, size.height);

            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PId == %d",[[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue]];
            NSArray *subTempArray = [self.replyCommentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

            lastHeight += 21;
            if (subTempArray.count > 0) {
                lastHeight += subTempArray.count * 21;

                float height = followBackView.frame.size.height;
                height += 21*subTempArray.count;

                followBackView.frame = CGRectMake(followBackView.frame.origin.x, followBackView.frame.origin.y, followBackView.frame.size.width, height);

                float followLabelHeight = 0.0;
                for (int j =0 ; j < subTempArray.count; j ++) {
                    NSDictionary *ohterMessage = [subTempArray objectAtIndex:j];
                    replyStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@reply%@: %@",[ohterMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[ohterMessage objectForKey:@"Comment"]];
                    TTTAttributedLabel *subCommentLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, followCommentLabel.frame.origin.y + followCommentLabel.frame.size.height + followLabelHeight, followBackView.frame.size.width, 21)];
                    //                                subCommentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                    subCommentLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
                    subCommentLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
                    subCommentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    [subCommentLabel setText:replyStr afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
                        NSRange redColorRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@reply%@:",[ohterMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Username"]] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                        // Core Text APIs use C functions without a direct bridge to UIFont. See Apple's "Core Text Programming Guide" to learn how to configure string attributes.
                        NSDictionary *colorDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:UIColorFromRGB(0xbf6327),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
                        [mutableAttributedString addAttributes:colorDic range:redColorRange];

                        return mutableAttributedString;
                    }];
                    [followBackView addSubview:subCommentLabel];

                    UIButton *subfollowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    subfollowButton.frame = subCommentLabel.frame;

                    NSString *subIdentify = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d",i,j];
                    [subfollowButton setTitle:subIdentify forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                    subfollowButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                    [subfollowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFollowComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    subfollowButton.tag = indexPath.row + 10000;
                    [followBackView addSubview:subfollowButton];
                    [followBackView bringSubviewToFront:subfollowButton];
                    //                            CGSize size = [followCommentLabel.text sizeWithFont:followCommentLabel.font
                    //                                                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240, 800)
                    //                                                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
                    //                            followCommentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 418, size.height);

                    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PId == %d",[[ohterMessage objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue]];
                    NSArray *subFollowTempArray = [self.replyCommentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
                    followLabelHeight += 21;
                    if (subFollowTempArray.count > 0) {
                        followLabelHeight += subFollowTempArray.count * 21;

                        lastHeight += subFollowTempArray.count * 21;

                        float height = followBackView.frame.size.height;
                        height += 21*subFollowTempArray.count;

                        followBackView.frame = CGRectMake(followBackView.frame.origin.x, followBackView.frame.origin.y, followBackView.frame.size.width, height);

                        for (int k =0 ; k < subFollowTempArray.count; k ++) {
                            NSDictionary *ohterFollowMessage = [subFollowTempArray objectAtIndex:k];
                            NSString *replyFollowStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@reply%@: %@",[ohterFollowMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[ohterMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[ohterFollowMessage objectForKey:@"Comment"]];
                            TTTAttributedLabel *subFollowCommentLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, subCommentLabel.frame.origin.y + subCommentLabel.frame.size.height + k * 21, followBackView.frame.size.width, 21)];
                            //                                subCommentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                            subFollowCommentLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
                            subFollowCommentLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
                            subFollowCommentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                            [subFollowCommentLabel setText:replyFollowStr afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
                                NSRange redColorRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@reply%@:",[ohterFollowMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[ohterMessage objectForKey:@"Username"]] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                                // Core Text APIs use C functions without a direct bridge to UIFont. See Apple's "Core Text Programming Guide" to learn how to configure string attributes.
                                NSDictionary *colorDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:UIColorFromRGB(0xbf6327),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
                                [mutableAttributedString addAttributes:colorDic range:redColorRange];

                                return mutableAttributedString;
                            }];
                            [followBackView addSubview:subFollowCommentLabel];
                        }
                    }

                }

            }


        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:followBackView];
    }
```

Comment: How about Recursion? http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=recursion_in_obj-c

Comment: That's very complicated code.  Move some of the functionality into (private) methods to simplify it.

Comment: yes,i really need a Recursion,but dont know how to wrire it, would you like to give me an simpale sample.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this may not be the exact solution. But you can follow this approach with some minor changes

```
- (NSArray *) replyforPid:(int) pID {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PId == %d",pID];
    NSArray *tempArray = [self.replyCommentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return tempArray;
}

- (void) addReplyInView:(UIView *) followBackView forPid:(int) pID lastHeight:(float) lastHeight {
     NSArray *tempArray = [self replyforPid:pID];
     if ([tempArray count] > 0) {
     if (lastHeight != 0) {
         float height = followBackView.frame.size.height;
         height += 21*subTempArray.count;

         followBackView.frame = CGRectMake(followBackView.frame.origin.x, followBackView.frame.origin.y, followBackView.frame.size.width, height);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.count; i ++) {
         NSDictionary *replyMessage = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *replyStr;
         replyStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Username"],[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Comment"]];
         TTTAttributedLabel *followCommentLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, lastHeight + 5, followBackView.frame.size.width, 21)];
         followCommentLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
         followCommentLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
         followCommentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         [followCommentLabel setText:replyStr afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
             NSRange redColorRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Username"]] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                // Core Text APIs use C functions without a direct bridge to UIFont. See Apple's "Core Text Programming Guide" to learn how to configure string attributes.
                NSDictionary *colorDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:UIColorFromRGB(0xbf6327),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
                [mutableAttributedString addAttributes:colorDic range:redColorRange];

                return mutableAttributedString;
        }];
        [followBackView addSubview:followCommentLabel];

        UIButton *followButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        followButton.frame = followCommentLabel.frame;

        NSString *identify = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [followButton setTitle:identify forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        followButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFollowComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [followBackView addSubview:followButton];
        [followBackView bringSubviewToFront:followButton];
        lastHeight += 21;
        [self addReplyInView:followBackView forPid:[[replyMessage objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue] lastHeight:lastHeight];
    }
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.commentArray.count > 0) {
        //comments
        NSDictionary *message = [self.commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([FHWServiceManager isValidObject:[message objectForKey:@"UserIcon"]]) {
            [cell.photoImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[message objectForKey:@"UserIcon"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face_poor"]];
        }else {
            cell.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face_poor"];
        }

        cell.photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        cell.photoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.nameLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"Username"];
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xbf6327);
        cell.contentLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"Comment"];
        cell.timeLabel.text = [DateUtil timePassedDescriptionFor:[DateUtil dateFromRFC3339DateString:[message objectForKey:@"CreateTime"]]];

        //follow comment
        NSArray *tempArray = [self replyforPid:[[message objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue]];
        if (tempArray.count > 0) {
            UIImageView *triangleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(67, 80, 10, 5)];
            triangleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment_reply_arrow_top"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:triangleImageView];

            UIView *followBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 85, 245, tempArray.count * 21 + 10)];
            followBackView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xf6f6f6);
            followBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            [self addReplyInView:followBackView forPid:[[message objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue] intValue] lastHeight:0.0];
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,kinda like this thing.now can get all the comments message,but show in the wrong place,as i had two level different style comment above this.so maybe i should use a block to re-assignment to the lastheight etc to calculate the parrent level comment's position:

Comment: something like :- (void)replyView:(NSDictionary *)message withBackView:(UIView *)followBackView withLabel:(UILabel *)subCommentLabel finished:^(float followLabelHeight, float  lastHeight){
    
    followLabelHeight += 21;
    
}  so  i can re-value the followLabelHeight bit.

Comment: You may need to alter the frame calculation (some logic with lastHeight will be better). From the code it is bit difficult to create a common logic for frame.

Comment: thanks again, how can i re-value the pass in param after the calculate. as i had three level different style comment ui,above code is just for the thrid level,so i should re-value some value back for calculate the above two level's position.